# Java: How to print Euro symbol on an receipt printer

Tags: java, printing, pos

I have a java application which needs to print the euro symbol on an Epson Tm20-II.

I've tried setting a var euro to include it in a string.

**printString method in a PrintService class**

```java
 public void printString(String printerName, String text) {

        // find the printService of name printerName
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                flavor, pras);
        PrintService service = findPrintService(printerName, printService);

        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        try {

            byte[] bytes;

            // important for umlaut chars
            bytes = text.getBytes("CP437");

            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);


            job.print(doc, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**The main function:**

```java
        String euro = "\u20ac";
        PrinterService ps = new PrinterService();
        String toPrint = new String();

        toPrint = ("Hello world, 5" + euro);

        ps.printString(printer, toPrint);
```

Instead of printing € it prints?

Comment: `public final static char euro = '\u20ac'; `

Comment: Thing is, codepage 437 doesn't support euro, that's when your € becomes a ? . Are you sure you need to involve this charset, or to call getBytes() at all? Sounds like cargo cult. I recommand trying other things.

Comment: @bakero98 is that supposed to do something?